# Autotools - set path to library

Tags: linux, autotools, autoconf, automake

In my debian system there is an installed library.
I wan't to make a patch to the library and to the application, that uses it.
So, I downloaded sources of library's and application's packages. Then I patched a library and built it (without installing it to the system).

Now, when I `./configure` the application, autotools detect the system's version of the library, not the mine one.
So, I did `./configure CFLAGS=-I/home/aquirel/dev/vte-0.28.2/src LDFLAGS=-L/home/aquirel/dev/vte-0.28.2/src/.libs`

Is there any more intelligent way to do it?
Because, using this approach generates libtool temporary wrapper script instead of a executable binary.

And also, I don't want to install a patched version of a library to the system till I have tested it in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install the `vte` package using the [DESTDIR](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/DESTDIR.html) install:

```
$ cd /home/aquirel/dev/vte-0.28.2
$ make DESTDIR=/home/aquirel/dev/test-vte install
```

This will install all the headers/libraries to `/home/aquirel/dev/test-vte` as if it were `/`.  You'll have to set up paths to `configure` a little differently:

```
$ ./configure CFLAGS=-I/home/aquirel/dev/test-vte/usr/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/home/aquirel/dev/test-vte/usr/local/lib
```

and setup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for the `vte` shared libraries as well for your application test environment.

> Because, using this approach generates libtool temporary wrapper script instead of a executable binary.

`libtool` always creates a wrapper script for applications that link shared libraries.  If you need to run your application under Valgrind or gdb, see here for more information about `libtool`'s [`--mode=execute`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Debugging-executables.html) option.